# license error while making connection ibm db2 using python and ibm_db library

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud, remote-server

I am trying to make connection with db 2 , so here is my code that i have used from the documentation

```
import _db 
conn=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=*LOCAL;HOSTNAME=*.*.*.*;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=uid;PWD=pwd",'','')
connState = ibm_db.active(conn)
print(connState)
```

The error which i get in return is

```
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598
```

I don't know how to resolve this , any help would be highly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: To which Db2 server? Is it to Db2 for z/OS?

Comment: i just checked its z/OS

Answer (score 2):

SQL1598N is a frequently asked question when connecting CLI drivers to either Db2-for-Z/OS native or  Db2-for-i (as/400, IBM i ,...).

When you do not have a licence file, the CLI driver will throw SQL1598N.

You can either purchase a licence (for Db2-connect-personal) and deploy it, **OR** you can avoid the need for a licence if any of the following are true:

- you want to connect to Db2-for-Z/OS and your company already has a Db2-connect gateway installed that you can use to gain indirect access to Db2-for-Z/OS.
- you want to connect to Db2-for-Z/OS and your Z/OS DBA knows how to configure server-based licensing instead of workstation based licensing
- you want to connect to Db2-for-i (as/400, IBM i...) and you already have installed the most recent version of IBM i access ODBC driver, which already includes a licence to connect to Db2-for-i.
- you can find or use a licence file (db2_connect_pe.lic or similar) on a different workstation that you can deploy legally to your workstation that runs python, into the clidriver license subdirectory
  IBM supplied CLI drivers (when packaged as "clidriver", or "Data Server Client") for both Db2-for-Z/OS  and Db2-for-i  are not free, and require a licence to be purchased and deployed, either directly or indirectly.  However, there is no licence required when the Db2-server runs on AIX/Linux/Windows/cloud x64. You only need the licence when the Db2-server runs on Z/OS native, or i-series.

For connecting to as400 (i series) only, if you already have installed "IBM i access" odbc option, then you DO NOT need a licence file **if and only if** you configure your tooling to use the IBM i access odbc driver (instead of clidriver or IBM Data Server client) and in your connection string in Python you mention the correct DRIVER= name (which you can find in the odbcad32 on Microsoft-Windows, or in the unixODBC configuration files).

For either clidriver or Data Server Client, that licence can be available **either** at the Db2-for-Z/OS end (ask your DBA about `db2connectactivate`),  or more commonly at the workstation end, or (in larger companies) can be avoided by connecting **indirectly** via a **Db2-connect** gateway product available separately from IBM.

When applied directly at the workstation, the license is a small file (with the extension .lic) that you must copy into the license subdirectory of your CLIDRIVER installation (or your Data Server Client installation). The license is tied (i.e. it must match) to the Db2-for-Z/OS release, and the license file can have different names depending on which product is purchased from IBM.

To get a licence file, ask your DBA, or purchase it (a Db2-connect personal license) from IBM Passport Advantage or through your reseller, or copy it from another workstation that does not use the license file.